# Passing variables to angular.js scope from web page

Tags: angularjs

What is correct way of passing variables from web page when initializing `$scope`?

I currently know 2 possibilities:

1. `ng-init`, which looks awful and not recommended (?)
2. using AJAX request for resource, which requires additional request to server which I do not want.

Is there any other way?

Comment: I think option2, using ajax

Comment: It depends on your application. I my opinion both options have their use cases.

Comment: But is there another option? Because I don't like neither :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those variables are able to be injected through `ng-init`, I'm assuming you have them declared in Javascript.

So you should create a service (`constant`) to share these variables:

```js
var variablesFromWebPage = ...;
app.constant('initValues', variablesFromWebPage);
```

With this service, you don't need to add them to the scope in the app start, you can use it from any controller you have, just by injecting it (`function MyCtrl(initValues) {}`).

Althouhg, if you do require it to be in the scope, then this is one of the main reasons what controllers are meant for, as per the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller):

> Use controllers to:
>
> - **Set up the initial state of a scope object.**
> - Add behavior to the scope object.

Just add this cotroller to your root node:

```js
app.controller('InitCtrl', function($rootScope, initValues) {
  $rootScope.variable1 = initValue.someVariable;
  $rootScope.variable2 = initValue.anotherVariable;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cunha: Tnx.

Here some more details how I did it:

In the Webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var variablesFromWebPage = {};
                variablesFromWebPage.phoneNumber = '@Model.PhoneNumber';
</script>
```

In the angular application file, registering the service:

```
var module= angular.module('mymodule', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);


module.factory('variablesFromWebPage', function () {
    return variablesFromWebPage
});
```

And then the controller:

```
module.controller('IndexController',

    function ($scope, $location, $http, $interval, variablesFromWebPage) {
        $scope.phoneNumber = variablesFromWebPage.phoneNumber;
    }
);
```